# decimal/double/float won't store decimal places

Tags: c#, integer, double, decimal

I have tried this with decimal, double and float variables. I am dividing an integer by another integer and storing the result in a variable. None of the three data types will store decimal points, for example:

```
double d;
uint num1 = 20
uint num2 = 3
d = num1 / num2;
//d = 6.0
```

It is as if it is rounding to the nearest integer, help please?

Comment: also read up on the following for good reference [C# MSDN Decimal.Divide Method()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.divide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks! Also, do you know why I have to convert it to a decimal when assigning it if there is no error about needing to explicitly convert it?

Comment: There should be at least one person asking the same question in the past... Diviindg 2 integers is somewhat common - so surprising you have not found any previous questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast either num1 or num2 as a decimal/double/float first before doing the division and storing the result..

Answer (score 2):

When you do math with integers, the result is an integer.  That's just how the operators are defined.  To do double math, make `num1`, `num2`, or both doubles, or cast one of them to a double before calculating.